# If Products are covered by API should the Cart functionality also be covered by API?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm working on a practice example where i add a bunch of products to a database that is carried out by a .Net Core API. After i use Angular to show it and work with the view part of the app.

Currently Im able to add products , show them on the screen , filter them and do different stuff with them. What I'm wondering is, how am i suppose to work it if for example a user wants to add the certain product in their personal Car ?

I was thinking of 2 ways:
Make a table in the databe that covers the Cart and use Foreign Key to the products and just have a POST to the Api to add item to the cart.

Or when a person clicks on the button in the Angular apps, it just adds to the cart that specific item the same way it shows it. With the GET method i have implemented in my API.

I'm not sure which way is better, or maybe i am wrong in both ways ?
What can you advice me ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're basically already going the microservices route; you just have only one service at the moment. The main thing you need to consider with microservices is what constitutes your app "domain" and what subdomains exist within that. Maybe carts and products are within the same subdomain and can thus be handled by the same service. The more likely thing, though, is that they are separate subdomains, and you should have a product service and a cart service.

The reason you need to consider your entire domain is because this will affect some of the maths here. Right now, you're just talking about products and carts, and maybe you can make a case for those being part of the same service. However, you're not going to stop there. Some sort of checkout process will obviously become a part of this (not much point in adding something to a cart otherwise). So, given that, it's reasonable to assume you might have a checkout service. Now, you have to ask, are carts part of *that* subdomain. Perhaps carts are a better fit for your checkout service than your product service, or maybe you need services for all three: products, carts, and checkout.

Long and short, there's no hard and fast rules here. You need to determine what your app's domain is and how that domain can be subdivided into independent services. Then, you'll need to determine how you'll coordinate work between those services and subdomains. This is your architecture; ultimately, you have to figure it out.